# After a fresh installation of Ubuntu 22.04 I can't use the eye-dropper or colorpicker anymore

Tags: software-installation, 22.04, software-sources

After a fresh installation of Ubuntu 22.04 (and updated) I can't use the eye dropper in DevTools or colorpicker in any application. When I use it, I get popup screen "Screen Share" For an example see the screenshots below:

[image: Screenshot DevTools]

[image: Screenshot after using eyedropper or colorpicker]

Has anyone know how to solve this issue and why it happens? I just want to use the eye dropper or the colorpicker for example in Elementor. This issue happens in Chrome and Opera when I use DevTools and in Elementor colorpicker.

With kind regards, Erkan.